# React.js: how does updating dynamic subcomponents work?

Tags: reactjs

In a scenario where a React component contains dynamic subcomponents, say a list component with n items, how does React determine when to update specific subcomponents? For example, if I reorder the list or replace it with another list having common elements, can I optimize performance by preventing the re-rendering of these reused elements? Or is React already optimizing re-renders so well that this would not make sense?

Comment: React already checks that. Every DOM element has a react-internal id that it verifies against the JS object backing it's using. If there are differences, it updates only the DOM parts that need updating. It leaves everything alone. Which is why it's essential you remember to use `key` attributes in things like `array.map()` content generators, because those are used to determine which DOM node belongs to which object backing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is where React's virtual DOM comes into play.

When you render stuff in React, it builds a big Javascript tree of regular elements. When the state changes and a re-render is triggered, the render function performs its reconciliation. It tries to figure out if any elements can be reused by comparing their type, attributes, and children.

For example:

```
<span id="A">Hello!</span>
```

React knows that this node:
  - Has a type of `span`
  - Has a single attribute, an `id` of "A"
  - Has a text node for children, consisting of the string "Hello!"

When a re-render is triggered, it examines the child to see if it matches. If it has the same type, set of attributes, and children, it knows it can skip rendering to the DOM.

---

**Dynamic lists**
The problem with this strategy is it doesn't take into account re-orderings. For example:

```
<span id="B"></span>
<span id="C"></span>
```

If, on the next render, it sees:

```
<span id="A"></span>
<span id="B"></span>
<span id="C"></span>
```

All we've done is add 1 new item, but because we added it to the top of the list, it compares B to A, and C to B. It cannot reuse the pre-existing B and C components and re-renders everything. Thankfully, there's a solution to this problem.

By giving an item a 'key', React knows to compare items of the same key:

```
<span id="B" key="1"></span>
<span id="C" key="2"></span>
```

Even if the order changes

```
<span id="A" key="3"></span>
<span id="B" key="1"></span>
<span id="C" key="2"></span>
```

React knows to compare 1 to 1, and 2 to 2. It only adds 1 new node, and leaves B and C alone.

**Further reading** 
React has [fantastic documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reconciliation.html) on this subject